# Get max values by category in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of dictionaries that looks something like this:

```
example = [
    {'id': 1, 'foo': 10, 'seq': 1, 'val':  0, 'sum':  0} ,
    {'id': 1, 'foo': 94, 'seq': 2, 'val':  5, 'sum':  5} ,
    {'id': 1, 'foo': 32, 'seq': 3, 'val': 32, 'sum': 37} ,
    {'id': 2, 'foo': 10, 'seq': 1, 'val':  0, 'sum':  0} ,
    {'id': 2, 'foo': 43, 'seq': 2, 'val':  3, 'sum':  3} ,
    {'id': 2, 'foo': 71, 'seq': 3, 'val': 14, 'sum': 17} ,
    {'id': 2, 'foo': 32, 'seq': 4, 'val':  6, 'sum': 23} ,
    {'id': 3, 'foo': 26, 'seq': 1, 'val':  0, 'sum':  0} ,
    {'id': 3, 'foo': 38, 'seq': 2, 'val':  8, 'sum':  8}
]
```

I need three key pieces of information from the list:

1) I need to identify highest 'seq' value for each 'id' in the list.

2) Using the results of (1), I need to compare the 'sum' value for each highest 'seq' value to the other highest 'seq' values and identify which 'seq' value has the lowest 'sum'.

3) This process is complicated by the fact that I also need to make the comparison based on the 'foo' value, such that the comparison in (2) only compares 'sum' values where the first and last 'foo' values are the same.

So, in the example list, I would want 'id' values 1 and 2 to be compared to each other since they start with 'foo' 10 and end with 'foo' 32.

Here's some pseudo code that I hope gets at what I'm looking to do:

```
def getMinId(foo1, foo2, exampleList):
    # first limit exampleList to only ids that match the foos
    # next find the minimum 'sum' among the remaining ids
```

The desired final output might look something like:

```
{(10,32): 23, (26,38): 8}
```

I can brute force this with a whole lot of iterating over lists, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it. The only result that really matters is finding the minimum 'sum' value for each 'foo' pair, so feel free to ignore the steps I've laid out here if there's a better way to think about it.

Comment: {10: 0, 26: 0, 32: 23, 38: 8, 43: 3, 71: 17, 94: 5} is that desired output?

Comment: Not quite. I'll alter the question with a clearer desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your example (in Python 2.7).  Be sure to test it on a larger data set.

**maxvaldict.py**

```
example = [
    {'id': 1, 'foo': 10, 'seq': 1, 'val':  0, 'sum':  0},
    {'id': 1, 'foo': 94, 'seq': 2, 'val':  5, 'sum':  5},
    {'id': 1, 'foo': 32, 'seq': 3, 'val': 32, 'sum': 37},
    {'id': 2, 'foo': 10, 'seq': 1, 'val':  0, 'sum':  0},
    {'id': 2, 'foo': 43, 'seq': 2, 'val':  3, 'sum':  3},
    {'id': 2, 'foo': 71, 'seq': 3, 'val': 14, 'sum': 17},
    {'id': 2, 'foo': 32, 'seq': 4, 'val':  6, 'sum': 23},
    {'id': 3, 'foo': 26, 'seq': 1, 'val':  0, 'sum':  0},
    {'id': 3, 'foo': 38, 'seq': 2, 'val':  8, 'sum':  8}
]

# Dictionary identifying highest 'seq' value for each 'id' in the list.
# {id: [seq, sum, first_foo, last_foo]}
maxiddict = {}
for rowdict in example:
    if not maxiddict.get(rowdict['id']) or rowdict['seq'] > maxiddict.get(rowdict['id'])[0]:
        if not maxiddict.get(rowdict['id']):
            maxiddict[rowdict['id']] = [rowdict['seq'], rowdict['sum'], rowdict['foo'], rowdict['foo']]
        else:
            first_foo = maxiddict[rowdict['id']][2]
            maxiddict[rowdict['id']] = [rowdict['seq'], rowdict['sum'], first_foo, rowdict['foo']]

# Dictionary of groups of maxiddicts grouped by a combined key of first_foo, last_foo
# {'first_foo, last_foo': [{id: [seq, sum, first_foo, last_foo]}]}
groupdict = {}
for k, v in maxiddict.items():
    key = ', '.join([str(v[2]), str(v[3])])
    if not groupdict.get(key):
        groupdict[key] = [dict([(k, v)])]
    else:
        groupdict[key].append(dict([(k, v)]))

# Dictionary of lowest sums of maxidicts entries grouped by combined key of first_foo, last_foo
lowestsumsdict = {}
for groupkey, groupvallist in groupdict.items():
    minsum = min([entry.itervalues().next()[1] for entry in groupvallist])
    lowestsumsdict[groupkey] = minsum

print lowestsumsdict
```

**output:**

```
(maxvaldict)macbook:maxvaldict joeyoung$ python maxvaldict.py 
{'26, 38': 8, '10, 32': 23}
```